# Parse php array('s) to json isn't work

Tags: php, json, cakephp-3.0

I've created a function in CakePHP 3 to get a list of content and a list of labels for a dynamic filled html table. But after I parsed the php array's to json the labels array isn't parsed. This will give me the "Cannot use 'in' operator...." error from the DataTables library.

When I log the parsed array you can see below that 'labels' is a normal array and content is a json array. I need two json array's.

```
{labels: Array(6), content: {…}}
```

**Parse php array to json inside my controller:**

```
public function ajaxGetContentList() {

    $allContent = this.getAllData();

    $contentArray = array();
    $labelArray = array();

    foreach ($allContent as $content) {
        if (isset($content->element->display)) {
            $contentArray[$content->form_id][$content->element->name] = $content->content;

            if(!in_array( $content->element->name, $labelArray)){
                 $labelArray[] = $content->element->name;
            }
        }
    }

    $data = [
       'labels' => $labelArray,
       'content' => $contentArray
    ];

    $content = json_encode($data);
    $this->response->getBody()->write($content);

    $this->response = $this->response->withType('json');
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

**Ajax call inside my view:**

```
function setContentListToTable() {
        $.ajax({
            url: websiteUrl + 'storages/list/' + '<?= $slug; ?>' + '/ajaxGetContentList',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {slug: '<?= $slug; ?>'},
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
                $('table').DataTable({ "columns": jsonArray.labels,"data": jsonArray.content});
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: convert `dataType: 'html',` to `dataType: 'json',` (then directly use `data`, no need to use `jQuery.parseJSON()`) or remove it (preferred way)

Comment: That's not working. The response will be the same as this `{labels: Array(6), content: {…}}`.